# Gap between background image and image in html

Tags: html, css

There is a gap between my background image and I wish to close that gap. How would I go around doing that?

I have tried removing the text, setting margins to 0, removing whitespace, placing the divs inline with each other, setting the background image as a standalone image in HTML, changing the height of the image. I am stumped!

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
        <h1 id="mainTitle">Sample Text</h1>
        <hr>
        <i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><h3 id="underTitle">Sample Text</h3>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sample Text">
    <div class="projects">
        <h1 id="proTitle">Sample Text</h1>
        <img src="images/codebg.jpg" alt="Sample Text" id="codeimg">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    font-family: 'Thasadith', sans-serif;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    top: 350px;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#mainTitle{ font-size: 100px;}
#underTitle{ font-size: 50px; margin-top: 10px;}

#mainTitle, #underTitle{
    transition: font-size 1s;
}
#mainTitle:hover{
    font-size: 110px;
}
#underTitle:hover{
    font-size: 60px
}
.fa-id-card{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-125px);
    top: 77%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
hr{
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
.btn{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    top: 560px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    transition: width 1s ease;
}
.btn:hover{
    color: white;
    width: 110px;
}

.projects{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    top: 1100px;
    /*background-image: url(images/codebg.jpg);*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
#proTitle{
    color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#codeimg{
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

Ideally, there should be no gap between the images

Thanks for any help anyone is able to provide

Comment: can you post your ideal result? It's the top value that messes it up but I'm not sure why u'r using it either. We may have better solution if know exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the position type of your image. 
Add this code in your CSS file:

```
img 
{
   position: relative;
   bottom: -4px;
}
```

I recreate your code changing the images. 
You can see in this link:
https://codepen.io/mvinnicius/pen/aPyObB

I hope help you

Comment: Didn't do the trick, probably because the position is set to absolute in the main div

Comment: @Owen try to decrease the bottom value to -14px; You can use my Codepen.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some minor changes that make it work:
CSS: Add `break.before` and `break.after` styles for your title id's

```
#mainTitle{
    font-size: 100px;
    break.after: 0;  }

#underTitle{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    break.before: 0; }

#mainTitle, #underTitle{
    transition: font-size 1s;   }

#mainTitle:hover{
    font-size: 110px;
    break.after: 0;  }

#underTitle:hover{
    font-size: 60px;
    break.before: 0; }
```

HTML: Trade `<div class="main">` for the Semantically correct `<main>`, then instead of using `<h1>` and `<h3>`(which force space around them), wrap it in a `<p>` tag.

```
<main>
    <div>
      <p><span id="mainTitle">Sample Text</span>
      <hr>
      <i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i><span id="underTitle">Sample Text</span>
      </p>
    </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Sample Text">
    <div class="projects">
       <h1 id="proTitle">Sample Text</h1>
       <img src="images/codebg.jpg" alt="Sample Text" id="codeimg">
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

play with .projects css
top and left